# Lectura de archivo excel protegido con contraseña phpspreadsheet

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

Tengo construido un lector de archivos xlsx y csv con php utilizando como lector phpspreadsheet pero al momento de leer archivos que están protegidos con contraseña no se puede.
Buscando en la documentación dice que "**phpspreadsheet puede leer las hojas de cálculo que están protegidas. No es necesario saber la contraseña ni hacer nada especial para leer un archivo protegido.**" pero no es tan así, ya que al leerlo me arroja el siguiente error de lectura.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿Alguien sabe algo con respecto a esto?

Comment: Por qué dices que no es tan así? QUé probaste? Qué pasó cuando ejecutaste esa prueba? Qué error sale? Qué debería pasar y qué pasó en su lugar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La explicación que viste en [la documentación](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#reading-protected-spreadsheet) hace referencia a **proteger** el archivo (de modificaciones), no a **encriptar** el archivo. Leer un archivo protegido, claro que se puede (porque no necesita modificarlo, sólo leerlo).

> If you need to completely prevent reading a file by any tool, including PhpSpreadsheet, then you are looking for "encryption", not "protection".

Abrir archivos encriptados, no se puede con sólo PHPSpreadsheet. Tienes que desencriptarlo y entregarle el resultado a PHPSpreadsheet para trabajar (los xlsx por ejemplo, son un zip glorificado con un montón de archivos dentro, siguiendo más o menos la especificación OOXML).

Hay personas que han creado cosas [como esta](https://github.com/jaydadhania08/PHPDecryptXLSXWithPassword) para lidiar con ese problema. El autor de esta librería sugiere algo como esto (aunque aclara que el código está sucio y no recomienda usarlo en producción):

```
require_once('PHPDecryptXLSXWithPassword.php');

$encryptedFilePath = 'hello world.xlsx';
$password = 'mypassword'; // password to "open" the file
$decryptedFilePath = 'temp_path_to_decrypted_file.xlsx';

decrypt($encryptedFilePath, $password, $decryptedFilePath);

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($decryptedFilePath);
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
echo $sheet->getCell('A1')->getValue() . "\n";
```

PD. Para próximas preguntas, procura compartir el código que genera el error que muestras. Pues, como para no adivinar

Comment: Muchas gracias!