# Puedo leer un excel con contraseña usando phpspreadsheet?

Tags: php, excel, aplicación-web

Estoy tratando de leer un archivo xlsx que está protegido con contraseña (la cual conozco), para luego pasarlo a formato html y embeberlo con un iframe. Todo esto con la librería phpSpreadsheet. Siempre termino en el mismo problema, y es que no sé como usar la contraseña para "desbloquear" el archivo. Probé muchas cosas pero nada... dejo lo que creo que tengo más o menos en buen camino. Con esto, el error que me da es que no está definido el método setWorkbookPassword. La pregunta que me hago ahora es: se puede hacer lo que quiero hacer? Si es así, como?

```
<?php
include 'vendor/autoload.php';

$file = "RutaArchivo.xlsx";
$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
$reader->setWorkbookPassword('Contrasenia');  
$sheet = $reader->load($file);
?>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu versión de PhpSpreadsheet? La última versión es `1.27.1`. Dicho eso, tu código no es conforme a lo que explica la documentación sobre [leer hojas protegidas](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#reading-protected-spreadsheet). También, hay que saber hacer la diferencia entre *protegido* y *encriptado*. La doc es clara al respecto: *Si necesita evitar por completo la lectura de un archivo con cualquier herramienta, incluida PhpSpreadsheet, entonces está buscando "cifrado", no "protección".* ¿De qué hablamos en tu caso?

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/559823) posiblemente sea lo que buscas. ;)

Comment: @A.Cedano La librería está en su última version. Ahora que mencionas la diferencia entre protegido y encriptado. Investigué y según entendí, cuando le asignas una contraseña al archivo en _Archivo>Informacion>Proteger libro>Cifrar con contraseña_, sería cifrado, cierto? Si es así, voy a optar por la respuesta que envía Israel-ICM, Muchas gracias por la respuesta!

Comment: @Israel-ICM Genial, gracias!

Comment: @ZoiloPazos, marcaré tu pregunta como duplicada puesto que ya se respondió anteriormente.

Comment: Si usas un método para *cifrar* (encriptar) está claro que hablamos de un archivo cifrado (encriptado) y según la documentación, PhpSpreadsheet NO puede leer un archivo encriptado. OTRA cosa es que protejas el archivo con una clave encriptada, en cuyo caso, según entiendo, deberías verificar la clave contra un hash. Me parece que eso es lo que hace el método `verify()` del ejemplo que muestra la doc (enlace de mi primer comentario). ¿Has probado con ese método? ¿No funciona? ¿Da algún error? No tengo la librería instalada, pero me parece que la respuesta referida no es la mejor solución.